# Using dictionaries to print out a string as a vertical banner in the terminal. PYTHON3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to write a program that takes in a word or phrase as input and then print out the string vertically in the terminal with the letters in the string being in a custom ASCII art style.

This is what I have so far:

```
input_string = input('Please enter a word or phrase: ')
string = input_string.upper()

H = '''
||    || 
||    ||
||||||||
||    ||
||    ||
'''

I = '''
||||||||
   ||
   ||
   ||
||||||||
'''

letter_dict = {'H' : H, 'I' : I}

for letter in string:
    if letter in letter_dict:
        print(letter_dict(letter), sep='\n')
```

I am currently testing it out with the letters 'h' and 'i' (I will eventually make a custom style for each letter). I am trying to enter 'hi' as an input and then it would be printed in the terminal like this:

```
||    || 
||    ||
||||||||
||    ||
||    ||

||||||||
   ||
   ||
   ||
||||||||
```

The error I am getting is 'TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable'. I am not sure what changes to make to my dictionary to make my code work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary values are accessed using square_braces (indexing operator). You have to use `letter_dict[letter]`.

**TL/DR**: If you want the letters to be printed in same line. You can use following code:

```
input_string = input('Please enter a word or phrase: ')
string = input_string.upper()

H = '''
||    || 
||    ||
||||||||
||    ||
||    ||
'''

I = '''
||||||||
   ||
   ||
   ||
||||||||
'''

letter_dict = {'H' : H, 'I' : I}

max_lines = lambda w: max([len(letter_dict[x].splitlines()) for x in w])
for i in range(max_lines(string)):
    for c in string:
        print(letter_dict[c].splitlines()[i], end=' ')
    print('')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using parenthesis to access a dictionary element. You should be doing `letter_dict[letter]` instead of `letter_dict(letter)`.